# count the number of specific nodes between two nodes

Tags: xslt, xpath

I want to count a node present between two nodes in XML. Below is a demo XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body>
  <a></a>
  <b></b>
  <b></b>
  <b></b>
  <a></a>
  <b></b>
  <a></a>
  <a></a>
  <b></b>
  <b></b>
  <a></a>
</body>
```

And I'm using the below XSLT.

```
  <xsl:template match="a">
    <xsl:text>Number of B </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding::a[1]/following::b)"/>
    </xsl:template>
```

My Current output.

```
 <body>
      Number of B 0
      <b></b>
      <b></b>
      <b></b>
      Number of B 6
      <b></b>
      Number of B 3
      Number of B 2
      <b></b>
      <b></b>
      Number of B 2

   </body>
```

But my expected output is as below.

```
   <body>
      Number of B 0
      <b></b>
      <b></b>
      <b></b>
      Number of B 3
      <b></b>
      Number of B 1
      Number of B 0
      <b></b>
      <b></b>
      Number of B 2

   </body>
```

Here basically I want to count between ever `a`.

please let me know how can i get this done.

Here is the working Example

http://xsltransform.net/6r5Gh3F

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is to create a key that links the `b` elements to the first following `a` element

```
<xsl:key name="b" match="b" use="generate-id(following-sibling::a[1])" />
```

Then you can count the `b` elements preceding the current `a` element like so:

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(key('b', generate-id()))"/>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:key name="b" match="b" use="generate-id(following-sibling::a[1])" />

    <xsl:template match="a">
        <xsl:text>Number of B </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="count(key('b', generate-id()))"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Nice suggestion for key usage, plus one.

Answer (score 1):

You can count the number of following `b`'s and subtract the number of `b`'s following the following `a`:

```
<xsl:template match="a">
  <xsl:text>Number of B </xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="count(following::b) - count(following::a/following::b)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Nice logic, plus one.